# In app purchase prompts sign in on app startup

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, storekit

I am using `StoreKit` for in app purchases in my iPhone game. The purchases all work correctly, however I am constantly being prompted when the app is opened to sign into an account which does not exist anymore.

I had one sandbox account that I used until I was getting an error in which pressing 'restore purchases' was restoring the purchase even if the user pressed 'Cancel' on the modal popup. Because of this I created a new sandbox account to try and restore purchases from an account which had not made any purchases. Unfortunately restore purchases still worked in this situation which is of course a problem. I thought it could be an issue with the old sandbox account still being on the device somewhere so I deleted it. For some reason, every time the app starts, I am still prompted to sign into this test account that has been deleted.

Research has lead me to believe that maybe somewhere a transaction was not finished and so it is trying to complete it every time the app starts? Does this sound plausible?

If you would like to see my code, let me know and I will update.

**Edit:** I have of course tried deleting the app and reinstalling and also signing out of all accounts along with a reboot of the device.

Answer (score 1):

> Research has lead me to believe that maybe somewhere a transaction was not finished and so it is trying to complete it every time the app starts? Does this sound plausible?

Not just plausible, but likely. Hack your app to call finish on all transactions regardless of actual completion state, then un-hack it.

Comment: Thanks for the response, do you know how I would do this? Do you know if there are way to remove or clear all pending transactions?

Comment: That's what I'm referring to. If my interpretation of your problem matches the actual problem, you have an iOS-maintained queue of pending transactions that are trying to get kicked off (that causes the request for login). Check your transaction observer -- do you get a notification of start? Immediately call the finish method on the SKTransaction in a hack-build of your app (the same thing you should be calling on successful completion of the purchase/delivery of a new IAP item).

Comment: Thank you I'll give that a try and get back to you

Answer (score 1):

To solve this I finally signed into the account it was prompting me to sign in to and then went through and purchased all of my IAPs again manually, this reset whatever hung action there was and fixed the issue.